# Sed help: add regex in find and replace in html files

Tags: regex, sed

I wanna to find and replace a tag with inner html and replace it with something.
I use this command but it has problem in regex.

```
find pages* -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\(<div class=\"IASBS_Date_en\">\)[.]\(<\/div>\)/Sallam Karim/g' {} \;
```

what should I write instead of `[.]`
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 4):

[Don't parse XML/HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), instead use a proper parser like [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) with a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

Example

### File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>foo</a>
        <div class="IASBS_Date_en">20180219</div>
        <b>bar</b>
        <c>base</c>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Command :

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -u '//div[@class="IASBS_Date_en"]' -v '20190101' file.html
```

### Edited file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a>foo</a>
    <div class="IASBS_Date_en">20190101</div>
    <b>bar</b>
    <c>base</c>
  </body>
</html>
```

You just have to replace your [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command with this one

Comment: thanks. `xmlstarlet` doesnt work with `-exec` . `find: ‘xmlstarlet’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hmumm, you have to install it :)